# A question about the use of "everywhere" in the sentence

Tags: word-choice

Recently I've stumbled upon this sentence on the internet:

> Home is everywhere your heart is.

Somehow it doesn't seem right to me. If I had to convey the same meaning, I would write something like this:

> Home is wherever your heart is.

Or this:

> Home is everywhere where your heart is.

Could you please clarify whether I'm right or not.

Comment: The standard phrasing is "*[Home is where the heart is](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Home+is+where+the+heart+is)*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of *[everywhere](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/everywhere)* permits the first example of the OP:

> adverb
>
> 1.0 In or to all places:
> *I’ve looked everywhere*
> *everywhere she went she was feted*

---

The definition of *[wherever](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wherever)* includes the second example:

> relative adverb
>
> 1.0 In or to whatever place (emphasizing a lack of restriction):
> *meet me wherever you like*
>
> 1.1 In all places; regardless of where:

---

*Where* is used as a relative adverb as suggested by the third example:

> 2.0 The place or situation in which:
> *this is where I live*

---

All four of the following constructions would be grammatically acceptable with slightly different nuances. The first would be idiomatic, while the fourth would be slightly redundant:

> - *Home is **where** the heart is.*
>   Meaning: Home is **the place in which** the heart is.
> - *Home is **wherever** the heart is.*
>   Meaning: Home is **in whatever place** the heart is.
> - *Home is **everywhere** the heart is.*
>   Meaning: Home is **in all places** the heart is.
> - *Home is **everywhere where** the heart is.*
>   Meaning: Home is **in all places** where the heart is.

If the original author intended to emphasize **all places**, then *everywhere* is the right selection.

Comment: I still have trouble understanding what is the difference between the third and the fourth. What exactly does "where" change?

Comment: The extra *where* in the fourth construction is an unnecessary redundancy, because the *where* in *everywhere* provides both the locational and relational component the sentence needs to make sense. Using the extra *where* might prompt the reader to guess that the author intended to emphasize **all places being home** in addition to the relationship between heart and home.

Answer (score 2):

> You can use **everywhere** literally, but the sentence probably uses 
>   it in an ***exaggerating way.***

- Home is (*every*) [where your heart is](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Home+is+where+the+heart+is).
- Home is [where](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Home+is+where+the+heart+is) (*ever*) [your heart is](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Home+is+where+the+heart+is).